# Ubuntu 15.04 : Samba Server Error. ' Unit samba.service failed to load: No such file or directory.'

Tags: networking, server, apt, samba

I tried getting Samba Server Using

```
sudo apt-get install samba*
```

but doing that I got this :

The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

> fusiondirectory-plugin-samba : Conflicts: gosa-plugin-samba but 2.7.4+reloaded2-2 is to be installed
>
> gosa-plugin-samba : Depends: gosa (= 2.7.4+reloaded2-2) but it is not going to be installed
>   E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

After this I found a smb.conf file in /etc/samba/smb.conf 
I wrote the share definitions and used the following command.

```
sudo service smbd start
```

and I got this:

> Unit samba.service failed to load: No such file or directory.'

I TRIED THE FOLLOWING:

```
sudo service samba start
sudo service samba restart
```

but I got the samething also service--status-all has no smb in it
Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I got a solution on this link

https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/samba-fileserver.html#samba-fileserver-installation

also the command ap